# How to get a String value into C++ from Java method using JNI

Tags: c++, java-native-interface, jnienv

I have a method in my Java class which returns a string . method signature currently ()Ljava/lang/String;
I could create the class and method id with JVM in my native call.
Have done GetStaticMethodID  etc... all are fine.

How to invoke this method? for example: env->CallIntMethod()  env->CallCharMethod()  .... which option to get a string back?

In C++ , I need to copy this string value retured by this Java method.
Note: I can change the signature of the method in the Jar if needed. Or can add another method to wrap the other one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A method that returns Java String should be called as

```
jstring js = static_cast<jstring>(env->CallObjectMethod(jobj, mId));
```

Now you can use

```
const char *cstr = env->GetStringUTFChars(js, nullptr);
```

Don't forget to release the string after use:

```
env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(js, cstr);
```

You may find it necessary to to release the Java local reference,

```
env->FreeLocalReference(js);
```

Comment: Thank you verymuch. I tested it. One more point to add, I had to cast the return value to jstring before using it.(jstring)env->CallObjectMethod(javaObjectInstance,javaMethodId);

Comment: could you please let me know if there is a 'accept' for the answer? I could not figure out in the page.  If you are mentioning one!!

Comment: There is a grey ✔, if you click it it will become green. That's how you *accept* an answer on Stack Overflow.